# Many to many field get through value

Tags: django, django-orm

```
relation = models.ManyToManyField(model, through='model_through')
```

How I can get the value through in a ManyToManyField

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Yes, and I read it, but what I need is the string of through, like model._meta.model_name

Comment: where do you want get it? template or view?

Answer (score 0):

`relation` is a manager. The way you access `objects` to retrieve data, use `relation` in the similar manner.